# Delphi scrolling Memo

Tags: delphi

Right now i have this code.

```
procedure TForm1.Memo1Change(Sender : TObject);
begin
  SendMessage(Informacje.Handle, EM_LINESCROLL, 0, Memo1.Lines.Count);
end;
```

The problem is that I can't scroll up MemoLines when new lines are added. I want to stop moving cursor to the end on scroll up, start back moving cursor to the end when scrollbar is at bottom. Thank **You** for help.
In others words. Imagine there is a IRC chat with Memo. New message, caret is at end of last message. Now i want to read previous messages usin scroll bar (up) but i cant cause there are newer messages which move carret back to bottom. I want to stop it on mouse wheel up, read messages and after that back to previous state (caret once again at end on new message) when i will scroll to the bottom.

Comment: Hmm. I will try. Imagine there is a IRC chat with Memo. New message, caret is at end of last message. Now i want to read previous messages usin scroll bar (up) but i cant cause there are newer messages which move carret back to bottom. I want to stop it on mouse wheel up, read messages and after that back to previous state (caret once again at end on new message) when i will scroll to the bottom. Is now clear?

Comment: What's the UI signal for having finished reading? I.e. when should the Memo resume normal behaviour?

Comment: For both. I will try now do it for RichEdit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a condition to decide whether to scroll to the bottom or not. The below seems to work with a simple test, it sums the top most visible line with the number of possible lines that the memo can show to find out if the last line is visible or not.

```
procedure TForm1.Memo1Change(Sender: TObject);
var
  LineCount, TopLine: Integer;
begin
  LineCount := Memo1.Perform(EM_GETLINECOUNT, 0, 0) - 1;
  TopLine := Memo1.Perform(EM_GETFIRSTVISIBLELINE, 0, 0);
  if (TopLine + GetVisibleLineCount(Memo1)) >= LineCount then
    SendMessage(Memo1.Handle, EM_LINESCROLL, 0, LineCount);
end;
```

where

```
function GetVisibleLineCount(Memo: TMemo): Integer;
var
  DC: HDC;
  SaveFont: HFONT;
  TextMetric: TTextMetric;
  EditRect: TRect;
begin
  DC := GetDC(0);
  SaveFont := SelectObject(DC, Memo.Font.Handle);
  GetTextMetrics(DC, TextMetric);
  SelectObject(DC, SaveFont);
  ReleaseDC(0, DC);

  Memo.Perform(EM_GETRECT, 0, LPARAM(@EditRect));
  Result := (EditRect.Bottom - EditRect.Top) div TextMetric.tmHeight;
end;
```

(You can cache the visible line count to avoid having to calculate it for every change in the memo.)

You may need to further tweak the code though, f.i. for the case where there are less lines in the memo that it can show. Also this code does not take the caret position into consideration.

Comment: "(TopLine + GetVisibleLineCount(Form1.Memo6)) >= LineCount"   if on single memom change there is more lines, code should look like this "(TopLine + GetVisibleLineCount(Form1.Memo6)) >= LineCount - extra_lines"

Comment: @user - Are the "extra_lines" account for the lines you've just added?

Comment: its for irc chat. Sometimes message is one line sometimes in more lines. IF message is in 3 lines then must be (TopLine + GetVisibleLineCount(Form1.Memo6)) >= LineCount -2